# Consider SocketTimeOut as a false case

Tags: scala, exception

In my Code I get 
`java.net.SocketTimeoutException`

when I try to access:

```
val dirC = new InitialDirContext()
val attr = dirC.getAttributes("dns:/"+domain, Array("MX"))
```

I wanna write a case where I get `verified = false` when there is a socketTimeOutException. 
Incase there is no exception I wanna return a `verified = true`.

I wanna do this because I want to consider a socketTimeOut exception as a false case.

Is it possible to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along the lines of

```
Try {
   val dirC = new InitialDirContext()
   val attr = dirC.getAttributes("dns:/"+domain, "MX")
   true 
} recover {
   case ste: SocketTimeoutException => false
   case e => throw e
}
```

This return `true` is there is no Exception, `false` if there is a `SocketTimeoutException`, or re-throws the Exception otherwise